# How to show pictures in listview in icons mode?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I use Delphi Tokyo to create firemonkey app and I need to display pictures like in this image:

[image]

Is there a way to edit TListView to make it look like this ?

Comment: Did you look at the demos that come with Tokyo (in C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\Samples\Object Pascal\Multi-Device Samples\User Interface\ListView)?

Comment: @KenWhite I did now and did not find what I need. I also tried to read all the documentation about ListView but did not also found what I need.

Comment: Strange. I see at least two of them that, while they do not directly do what you're asking, show you exactly how to customize the appearance of the listview to something that would adapt to your needs. See ListViewCustomBottomDetail, for instance, or ListViewAddThumbAndCaption.

Comment: For something like what's in the picture, create a control or frame that has instances of image, text etc. Use a TFlowLayout inside a scrollbox, create instances of the composite control and add them to the TFlowLayout

Answer (score 1):

I did a similar project by using a TGridLayout inside a VertScrollBox component...

Steps...

- Put a VertScollBox in your form
- Put a GridLayout (inside the vert scroll) * sometimes the scrollbox
  dont want to behave correcly because of the witdth (or hight) of the
  grid... I normally adjust that thru a procedure.
- Add a button (anywhere outside of the vertScroll)

procedure to add an item...

```
var
  pnl : TPanel;
begin
  pnl := TPanel.Create(self);
  pnl.text := 'hi there!';
  // here you should create and add images to panel. make sure the parent of each object is the pnl object.
  pnl.parent := GridLayout1;
end;
```

The following code is called when resizing, when adding, and when removing an item.

```
procedure TfrmMain.adjustViews;
var
  itemsPerRows: double;
  rows: double;
begin
  // for grid on vertical scroll  
  if GridLayout1.ControlsCount > 0 then begin
    itemsPerRows :=  trunc(GridLayout1.Width / GridLayout1.ItemHeight);
    rows   := GridLayout1.ControlsCount / itemsPerRows;
    GridLayout1.height := rows * GridLayout1.ItemWidth;
  end;


  // for grid on horizontal scroll
  if GridLayout2.ControlsCount > 0 then
    GridLayout2.Width := GridLayout2.ControlsCount * GridLayout2.ItemWidth;
end;
```

notes:

- this post was typed directly, so you have an idea, but not from my
  code itself!

Hope it helps!